# Chrome app windows not obeying Breeze color settings in Plasma 5 (5.18.4)

Tags: display, google-chrome, kde, plasma

Every time I spawn an app window from Google Chrome using the default Breeze White theme, I notice that its title bar text displays in black, just as the title bar background is. Everything else in Chrome displays OK though. This doesn't happen with other stuff I run in KDE Plasma 5. Is there something special I have to do to Chrome to make it play nice with Plasma 5 and upcoming versions of Plasma?

Comment: Could you explain how you "spawn an app window from Google Chrome"?

Comment: Click on the hamburger menu in the menu bar (all the way at the far right) and select Create Shortcut from the More Tools submenu.

Comment: I did that leaving "open as window" unchecked. The shortcut seems to open as normal window: the title bar text is nearly white and the title bar background is nearly black. This is with Breeze or Breeze Dark or Kubuntu as the Global Theme. I don't see Breeze White as an option. This is with Plasma 5.18.4 on Kubuntu. Checking "open as window" gives me a window without a title bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcDlP.png

Comment: So what you're saying is don't use the Open as Window option anymore?

Comment: Frankly, I don't use Chrome's app windows. I was only trying to see if I could reproduce your issue of dark text on a dark background in the titlebar. I couldn't.